# Suppress SAP Information popup while executing VBA script

Tags: sap-gui

I have an scripting code with vba that is working fine for some transactions, however for `ZM52` transaction I am receiving a pop up information window when executing the report and for that reason is not working.

The problem is that is a big report, which takes time to download and this pop up is showing more than once.

Is there any option to "say" to SAP to avoid/omit/suppress this kind of information?

[image: Pop up message]

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you all

Comment: `ZM52` is a custom transaction developed at your company so nobody can help about how to hide it. Why don't you simply say in your script to ignore this popup at the time it's displayed? If you record the user action, you should get the name of this popup when you press Enter, and I guess you should be able to determine if it's displayed or not.

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi. I couldn't get what you mean by have tried it with a while loop that is pressing Enter while that pop up is open, since the number of pop ups in each execution is variable. So doing it, seems to work but I have to check it with more cases.
While objSess.findById("wnd[1]")
objSess.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Wend
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution by using the following code:

```
While objSess.ActiveWindow.Text = "Information" 
objSess.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press 
Wend
```